# ADO.NET 2.0 driver throws exception on CreateCommand()

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm using  ADO.NET 2.0 driver from Embracadero and trying to connect to remote Interbase base (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25497). I'm trying to do insert query to my database, but when I do insert query it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Does anybody have the same problem?

I have:

```
    public DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        DbConnection con = new TAdoDbxConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

        return con;
    }
```

and then I do:

```
        using (var conn = GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            { 
                cmd.CommandText = query;

                var param = cmd.CreateParameter();// <---- here exception is thrown
                NazwaChannel.ParameterName = "@param";
                NazwaChannel.Value = 1000;
                NazwaChannel.DbType = DbType.Int32;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
```

query is like "Insert into Table (tableID, columnname) values (GEN_ID(GenaratorName, 1), @param)".

Comment: Well first of all, we need some code to be able to help you. Also, if you have a nullpointerexception, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: Just one suggestion. Grab the value of the query variable and try to insert in the DB directly to see if the problem is in the query. Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Bas, it's not nullpointexception

Comment: And one more suggestion - try to open the connection for test just before the cmd.CreateParameter(); and see if you get the same or similar error on the conn.Open() line. Then we will know that it is related to establishing the connection with the remote DB.

Comment: When I do query like "Insert into tablename(id, param) values (uniqueId, 1)" everething is ok

Comment: finally, it could be solved by adding conn.Open() before using cmd.CreateCommand() xD
But now it throws exception unknown token "@".

Comment: Were you able to get hold of the auto generated ID value ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

- using conn.Open() before parameter creation
- instead of 'INSERT INTO TABLENAME (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (@value1, @value2, ...)' use 'INSERT INTO TABLENAME (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (? , ?, ...)'.